# How to get all records from a module - SugarCRM version 7+

Tags: json, sugarcrm

According to the [documentation](http://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_7.9/Integration/Web_Services/v10/Examples/PHP/How_to_Manipulate_Records_CRUD/), to query a record, you have to use this endpoint  `/<module>/:recordId`, but what if I want to get all records from a given module ? I can't find any documentation for this.

I tried `/<module>/filter` to set json parameters like this :

```
{
    "max-num": "-1",
    "offset": "0",
    "order-by": "date-entered",
    "favorites": false,
    "my-items": false
}
```

But returns only 20 records ?

Of course I tried to customize `"max-num"` with plenty of numbers but still returns 20 records.

I need help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option's name is `max_num` (containing underscore character), *not* `max-num`.

However there is another limit on the server-side that will overrule your `max_num` if its value is too high.
The default server-side max limit is 1000, but that can be increased in config by setting `$sugar_config['max_record_fetch_size']` to the desired number.

If you want to make sure that you get all records, it's generally a good idea to check `next_offset` in the response.
As long as it is not `-1` there are more records than were returned.
In such a case you should send another request with the `next_offset`'s value as `offset` in the request, to get the next "page" of records.

**Notes**

- I recommend to specify a `fields` array with the names of the fields you need in your requests. Otherwise you might end up with wasting a lot of time/bandwith/memory when retrieving a lot of records.
- Setting `$sugar_config['max_record_fetch_size']` will also effect e.g. how many records you can with "select all" in the list views.

**Paging Example**

In the following example we are going to fetch all records from the server, in batches/pages of 1000 per request. For this example let's assume that the server has 2341 records in total.

We request 1000 records, starting at offset `0`, which is the first record available:

*Request #1*

```
{
    offset: 0,
    max_num: 1000
}
```

Note: if no offset is specified, then 0 is assumed.

*Response #1* from Server

```
                             {
                                 next_offset: 1000,
                                 records: [array of 1000 records]
                             }
```

We receive the first 1000 records (offsets 0 to 999) in *Response #1*, the offset for the first record that we do **not** have yet is `1000` as specified in `next_offset`

Therefore we request 1000 records again, starting with record at offset 1000:

*Request #2*

```
{
    offset: 1000,
    max_num: 1000
}
```

*Response #2* from Server

```
                             {
                                 next_offset: 2000,
                                 records: [array of 1000 records]
                             }
```

We receive the next 1000 records (offsets 1000 to 1999) in *Response #2*, the offset for the first record that we do **not** have is `2000` as specified in `next_offset`

Therefore we request 1000 records again, starting with record at offset 2000:

*Request #3*

```
{
    offset: 2000,
    max_num: 1000
}
```

*Response #3* from Server

```
                             {
                                 next_offset: -1,
                                 records: [array of 341 records]
                             }
```

In *Response #3* we receive 341 records (offsets 2000 to 2340) and a `next_offset` with `-1`, indicating that there are no more records.
That means we have now received all 1000 + 1000 + 341 = 2341 records available.

Overview of results:

```
 ______________________________
|                              |  \                  \
|                              |   |                  \
|         "Page 1"             |   |__ 1000 records    |
| records at offset     0..999 |   |                   |
|                              |   |                   |
|______________________________|  /                    |
|                              |  \                    |
|                              |   |                   |__ all 2341 records
|         "Page 2"             |   |__ 1000 records    |
| records at offset 1000..1999 |   |                   |
|                              |   |                   |
|______________________________|  /                    |
|                              |  \                    |
|         "Page 3"             |   |__  341 records    |
| records at offset 2000..2340 |   |                  /
|______________________________|  /                  /
```

Comment: Can you please show me an example for the next_offset ?
So the response when I put "max_num":1000 is
"next_offset": 1000.

Comment: Sure. I'll add an example (in an hour or so, I'm currently on the move). I will let you know after I edited my answer :)

Comment: Ok I finally found out by myself  :) Thanks for your help Jay

Comment: Oh great, good job! I appended an example to my answer anyways, in case it could help somebody else :)

Comment: Hey Jay can you help me with something else please ?
I've posted a topic : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50923733/how-to-get-all-module-fields-sugarcrm-7-api-v10

Comment: Btw what an answer !