# How to get all fields from a module - SugarCRM 7+ api v10

Tags: sugarcrm

How to fetch every fields of a module in SugarCRM with its v10 api ?

In rest v4 we had `get_module_fields` to fetch fields.

My question is basically the same as [this one](https://community.sugarcrm.com/thread/24456)

When I try `http://<sugarcrm>/rest/v10/metadata`, Postman tells me that I need to enable Javascript !

Comment: There probably is only a 2-step solution. That is #1 fetching the metadata - which contains definitions of that module has which fields and #2 specifying all the fields in your request's `fields` array. Maybe there is another way to do it, e.g. by passing a special `view` in the request. I'll investigate and provide details later today :)

Comment: By the way: Not sure why Postman says it needs Javascript. Maybe because the data is too much to display as plain-text?
You could try to reduce the response payload by limiting it to the module you need: e.g. for Accounts module `/rest/v10/metadata?module_filter=Accounts&type_filter=modules`

Comment: Yes thats what I did and it worked.
Maybe You can post it so I can mark it as solved
For the Javascript, i just added https and it worked. Not sure why but doesn't matter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why Postman says it needs Javascript.
Maybe because the data is too much to display as plain-text? You could try to reduce the response payload by limiting it to the module you need:

e.g. for Accounts module: `/rest/v10/metadata?module_filter=Accounts&type_filter=modules`

You can find the list of fields in responseData.modules.<module>.fields

Supply all the fields' names in the `fields` array of your module/filter requests to receive their contents.

Comment: You could also look for the field names in the Studio in the Administration of sugar CRM. Then add them to the receiving model like Jay said

Comment: @Mark That's a good point. Another way to get all field names of a Module via code, e.g. in the JS Web-Console of your browser is: `_.pluck(App.metadata.getModule("Accounts", "fields"), "name")`